# How would I initialize an array of 'int' as a class member in c++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, integer

Okay, A simple question, but I CANNOT find the answer I had before...

Here it is.

I updated my compiler and such to c++11, and due to this, I cannot initialize arrays like I could beforehand. Here is the code:

```
class Something{
public:
    int array[5];
    void doSomething();
};

void Something::doSomething()
{
    array={1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

This worked completely fine beforehand, I implemented it into my new project (but lost the code due to a recent melting...) and cannot remember how I did it for the life of me. And I know it was extremely similar, but got an error at every attempt. I even tried:

```
class Something{
public:
    int array[5];
    void doSomething();
};

void Something::doSomething()
{
    int Temparray[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    array[]=Temparray[];
}
```

And still nothing...I cannot figure out what it is and bashing my head against google wasted 2 hours of programming...

Comment: This never worked. You seem to have been relying on some compiler extension, some kind of bug, or merely your faulty memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `std::array`

```
#include <array>

class Something{
public:
    std::array<int,5> array;
    void doSomething();
};

void Something::doSomething()
{
    array = std::array<int,5>{1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

Alternatively, copy the contents:

```
class Something{
public:
    int array[5];
    void doSomething();
};

void Something::doSomething()
{
    int tmp[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::copy(
            std::begin(tmp), 
            std::end(tmp), 
            std::begin(array)); // beware of buffer overrun
}
```

Comment: Alright, I guess I will have to deal with this. I can still use `array[x]` with the first option right?

Comment: @Molma yes, both actually

Comment: Just got an error from both attempts: 1) `array is not a member of std`. 2) `begin is not a member of std`...

Comment: Found an alternate to your alternate solution: `std::copy(tmp,tmp+4,array);` worked perfectly :)

Comment: Except that it will be wrong if the size of the array ever changes and the other approach works for `vector`, `deque`, `list`, etc. as well :) Just pick what you need, of course

Comment: Oh, by the way, (missed your earlier comment), make sure you're enabling c++11 mode (`-std=c++11` on GCC/Clang)

Comment: Maybe you missed `#include <array>` and `#include <iterator>`?